How to enable multi-payment in the NFT marketplace like ETH, USDT, MATIC, DAI, etc?
Hope you are doing great.
I'm trying to build a NFT marketplace with multi-payments.
When users buy a NFT, they must be allowed to pay with any of the payments such as ETH, USDT, MATIC, DAI...
How to implement that ?
Thanks in advance.

When you mean any payments, do you mean only other ERC20,or also other cryptocurrencies, or even other Layers of blockchain (L2, L3) ?
The three have 3 different answers.

If you mean other ERC20, then you just need to use the Interface IERC20.
as such : IERC20(token_address).transferFrom(_from; _to, _amount) making sure the allowances are right.

If you mean an other cryptocurrency, then that means a different Blockchain. And there might be several ways to go at it:
Such as payment gateways, or crosschain solutions.

If you mean other Layers such as polygon, optimism... then bridges or crosschain solutions (such as axelar or else) may be the right fit for you.


With little explanation such as your post it's difficult to give a detailed and in depth solution.
Make sure to provide more information, description, context,  why not links to a repository ...
